# conversion of multiple ascii characters in a char array to single int using their ascii values --- c/c++

Tags: c++, c, ascii

anyone know a good way for doing this conversion?

for example, take the char array holding ascii charcters "ABC", the int conversion i'm looking for would change those characters to a single int with value 656667.

any help would be very much appreciated.

*edit*
really appreciate the replies. as someone noted i did say char array, and specifically this is a byte array, so there could be multiple '\0' or NULL elements followed by additional ascii's. using methods like strlen, etc will cause problems. thanks again for the current input.

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: What would "foobar" be converted to?  The decimal value of a non-control ascii character may be two or three digits.

Comment: this isn't homework. i'm trying to come up with a good way of parsing a udp packet protocol. i'm self-taught and if i were to claim any teachers it would be this community. thanks for the cynicism though.

Comment: "foobar" would convert to 1021111119897114

Comment: Not being cynical, just trying to help you avoid hate from the haters.  In fact, I posted a solution for you.  Even if it were homework, I'd still help.

Comment: How should single digit ASCII values be printed? Is adding a leading zero necessary?

Comment: hi mak, no single digits would appear as single digits. so, if the first element in the char array held a TAB, the int representation would be 9.

Comment: Is there a limitation on the length of the char array?
how big is your int?

Comment: the max size will be known ahead of time. the max size of the int will be 32.

Comment: ok, so you are looking to create an integer that holds the decimal values of each ascii character in some order.....   Is there any reason they can't be hex?

Comment: are there any endianism concerns?

Comment: @EvilTeach: endian concerns are a whole seperate problem.  OP can ntohX() stuff as he pulls it off the wire.

Comment: @john  it depends.  If he is crossing platforms then the solution i have in mind won't work.

Comment: sorry evil, i should have said, max length of the int will be 32. re: endianism, i'm a little ignorant on that subject and am reading up about that right now.

Comment: So tell me is 99 two tabs or 'c'?

Comment: i think i understand now about endianism concerns. if the other computer on the network is from a different platform, then the byte encoding could be different. so, to answer your question, i don't believe there will be any endian concerns. thanks

Comment: hi jmucchiello, it could be either one. thanks.

Comment: Based on jim's comment that this is for parsing a network protocol, I believe the character array to integer value is the wrong approach to your needs. The issues are creating a function  that is both one-to-one and onto (in the mathematics & computer science sense). Otherwise you can not be certain of correctly encoding and decoding of the protocol. Others have also identified network / processor portability. If a network protocol isn't network portable, it is typically considered broke by design.

Comment: I'd suggest closing this question, and ask a new question about what you are trying to achieve in regards to network protocols. For example, are you trying to write an application that supports an existing protocol? Are you trying to create a binary network protocol and an application that uses such a protocol?

Comment: I have a simple solution. But do you need "AB\0C" to be printed as 6566067 or 656667?

Comment: I think the real question want to ask may be about trying to pack / unpack a UDP packet payload that contains binary data. Correct? 

I will also point out that you cannot simply write a C struct (structure) to an I/O stream because the C (and I believe C++) standards allow the compiler to align or pad struct's for quicker access. I don't know if this is what you are trying to work around.

Comment: mctylr, good points, and yes that's what i'm trying to do (unpack a udp payload), but i was trying to simplify the problem scope down to a degree that i could understand without introducing socket/protocol specific information. basically, i needed to understand the basics of byte level transforms. i think i have a much better grasp of it now. you're right, i should probably start a new question with that specific goal in mind. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, one got to look at the actual problem.

Parsing a packet protocol may or may not be easy, depending on the specification, but you can usually do better than throwing it all in a string...

If you don't know about them, look up `Google Protocol Buffer`, they can't be used as is, but the idea is there.

```
class UdpPacket
{
public:
  UdpPacket(const char str[], size_t length);

  uint16_t sourcePort() const { return mSourcePort; }
  unit16_t destinationPort() const { return mDestinationPort; }
  // ... The 3 other getters
private:
  uint16_t mSourcePort;
  uint16_t mDestinationPort;
  uint16_t mLength;
  uint16_t mCheckSum;
  std::string mData;
}; // class UdpPacket


UdpPacket::UdpPacket(const char str[], size_t length):
  mSourcePort(0), mDestinationPort(0), mLength(0), mCheckSum(0),
  mData()
{
  if (length < 8) throw IncompleteHeader(str, length);

  memcpy(mSourcePort, str, 2);
  memcpy(mDestinationPort, str, 2);
  memcpy(mLength, str, 2);
  memcpy(mCheckSum, str, 2);
  mData = std::string(str+8, length-8);
} // UdpPacket::UdpPacket
```

Net advantage ? You now have structured data. Of course there might be some endianness issue going on with the `memcpy`... you'll have to check for it.

Now, I don't know what your `mData` is supposed to be, but of course it would be better if it was structured too.

Using a simple `int` to store what does not look like an `int` at all, really is a bad idea I think... unless it was an `int` to begin with of course.

Comment: hm, that's interesting. thanks matthieu. i'm wondering, instead of doing all those memcpys... would it be possible to cast the packet directly? thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char start[]="ABC";
    char output[100];
    int i;
    char* output_start=output;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        output_start+=sprintf(output_start,"%d",start[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n",output);
}
```

This uses the `sprintf` function to print each character individually into a string. This avoids problems that can appear with other approaches that can arise if the ASCII values of the `char`s are not always two digits.

**Edit**: In light of your latest update, you might want to use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: What if the input (`start`) is not 3 characters long?

Comment: @ezod: The OP said *`char` array*, not *string*, so I did not assume anything. The size of the array needs to be supplied. Of course, if the OP actually did mean a string, he can always use `strlen`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what end result is desired.  It seems to me, though, that converting "ABC" to an integer 656667 has a lot of value.  The problem is that the result is ambiguous. Are you maybe not wanting to convert it to 0x414243?  If so, then memcpy would work.

Edit:  The result can be ambiguous if the character set is not confined to a specific range (specifically 0-99). I believe that ASCII characters are considered all those characters from 0 to 127 (0x7f).  Turning the result into an integer by concatenating the decimal values together results in a value that is ambiguous.  For example, the string `"xy"` has the individual decimal values of 120, 121.  By the original problem definition, the result would be 120121.  This could be decoded either as 12, 01, 21 or as 120, 121.  Both result in valid ASCII characters.  But, again, without knowing all the problem constraints, this could be perfectly valid.

Comment: could you please explain how the result would be ambigous?

Comment: Lower case 'd' through 'z' are 3 digits long. At some point this can cause problem reading the result.

Comment: maybe its used in some advanced algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You are really better off, going for bytes (*256) instead of decimal (*100) as it lets you use any value in the character set.

It is also better to use an unsigned int, instead of an int, as it will avoid signed/unsigned issues.

If you are doing a network transfer, then converting the value to network byte order, is very good advice.

```
unsigned int func(const char s[], size_t size)
{
    const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s;
    unsigned int result = 0;
    size_t z;
    for (z = 0; z < size; z++)
    {
        result *= 256;
        result += us[z];
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have not tested the above code.

Comment: hi evil, thanks for this example. could you explain a bit more about converting to network byte order? thanks

Comment: There is a nice discussion of the topic here.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/structure_bit_ordering.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char *str = "ABC";
  int i, n;

  for (i=0,n=0; i<strlen(str); i++, n*=100) {
    n += str[i];
  }
  n /= 100;

  printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Not beautiful but it will do the task.

Comment: the only problem with this, is that the character array may have multiple '\0' char's followed by other ascii's. in that case strlen would only count up to the first '\0'. thanks though.

Comment: @jim: Does that mean you are aware in advance of the length of the array?

Comment: hi ezod. yes, the length of bytes in the array is known ahead of time as it is the result of a socket recv call. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using C++, taking the resulting string and converting it an int is left as an exercise for the OP

```
std::string StringToDec( const char *inString )
{
    if ( inString == NULL )
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        std::ostringstream buffer;
        std::string String = inString;

        for ( std::string::iterator it = String.begin(); it != String.end(); it++ )
        {
            buffer << std::setw(2) << std::dec << int(*it);
        }

        return std::string ( buffer.str().c_str() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char * input = "ABC";
    char output[ 256 ];
    int n = 0;

    while( *input )
        n += sprintf( output + n, "%d", *input++ );

    printf( "%d\n", atoi( output ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Relies on the string being null-terminated. Hardcode size of `output` as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I noted in your post you said "char array" -- notably, NOT a string.  Assuming you actually mean a char array and not a null-terminated string, none of the posted sprintf-type solutions will work.

Here's a simple mathematical method not using string processing.

```
char str [] = {'A','B','C'};
int ret = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); ++i )
{
    ret *= 100;
    ret += str[i];
}
```

UPDATE:

If you're looking for a solution that does not rely on multiplication (for speed, perhaps), you can use shifts, too:

```
int ret = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); ++i )
{
    ret = ((ret << 2) + ret) << 1;  // ret *= 10
    ret = ((ret << 2) + ret) << 1;  // ret *= 10
    ret += str[i];
}
```

Someone else may have another shift operation sequence that multiplies by 100 directly -- I do not.  Also note that you can account for non-printable characters 0-256 simply by using 3 bytes to represent characters instead of two.  Although you're going to quickly run out of room in C++ native types:

```
char str [] = {0, 123, 'A'};

unsigned __int64 ret = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); ++i )
{
    ret = ((ret << 2) + ret) << 1;  // ret *= 10
    ret = ((ret << 2) + ret) << 1;  // ret *= 10
    ret = ((ret << 2) + ret) << 1;  // ret *= 10
    ret += str[i];
}
```

Comment: Only if all of the characters in the string are represented by between decimal 10 and decimal 99.

Comment: True, but that is an invariant of the problem itself.  Note the desired result in the OP for the chars 'ABC': 656667.

Comment: john thank you. your shift solution is really interesting. i have actually seen that before, but never sure how it worked. i need to play around with these more to understand how they work.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII values of most of the lowercase alphabets exceeds 99, so your question is valid only for uppercase letters.  If you are sure that characters on your system are ASCII encoded (i.e., `'A'` is 65 for example), most of the solutions above will work.  Otherwise, for maximum portability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char *const upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int A = 65;
    /* changed: since it's a char array, not necessarily a string */
    const char in[3] = "ABC";
    unsigned long long out = 0;
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i < sizeof in; ++i) {
        char *found = strchr(upper, in[i]);
        if (found) {
            if ((ULLONG_MAX - (A + (found - upper))) / 100 < out) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Overflow at %c\n", in[i]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            out = out * 100 + A + (found - upper);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Giving up at %c\n", in[i]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    printf("%llu\n", out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(I am assuming you want a number that has the value 656667 for `"ABC"` for example, and you don't just want to print.)

Comment: hm, i should have put lower case letters in their as well. it's ok if the ascii value represent 3 digits.

Comment: Well, extending the above for lowercase is left as an exercise :-).

Comment: Your problem is not well-defined, and based upon your recent edits, looks like you need to come up with a better encoding scheme.  I would delete my post, but will let it stay here because it technically does what you want to do, to a large extent.

Comment: i didn't mean that in a mean way. it wasn't meant to be sarcastic. your example was helpful and i was amused by the challenge. i should have followed my comment by with a :) as well. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @jim: no, I am not offended.  I am saying that what you're doing is a poor way of encoding data.  If you want to send some char array over the network, you don't need any conversion, and even if you do, the encoding you have is not a good one.

Comment: ok. the problem though, is that i'm not encoding, i'm receiving. i have no say in the msg protocol unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving what you think you're receiving?  You might actually be receiving the correct data.  Can you post an example of the raw bytes you get?  For example, after receiving 3 bytes that are supposed to represent `"ABC"` in `data`, what do you get if you do `printf("%.3s", data);`?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's for a network protocol, you have to specify endianness.  You're putting bytes into an `int` in a certain order, and asking about the value.  Bytes go into `int`s in two different orders.  This doesn't matter on one individual computer, since computers don't change endianness at a whim, but you can easily get two different values on two different computers.

That being said, there's various ways to convert.  One is using a `union`, and one is to cast between `int *` (or `unsigned int *`) and `char *`.  Just make sure you're using a consistent byte order.

Comment: hi thanks david. could you explain a bit more about making sure to use a consistent byte order? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works. This will print "AB\0C" as 6566067. If you want it to be printed as 656667, then remove `if (!val) rv *= 10;`

```
int asciiToInt(char *str, int len) {
    int i;
    int rv = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int val = str[i];
        if (!val)
            rv *= 10;
        while (val) {
            rv *= 10;
            val /= 10;
        }
        rv += str[i];
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

struct printer {
    std::stringstream& s;
    printer(std::stringstream& stream_) : s(stream_) { };
    void operator()(char& c) { s << static_cast<int>(c); } 
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::stringstream helper;
    char* in = "ABC";
    std::for_each(in, in+3, printer(helper));
    int result;
    helper >> result;
    std::cout << result; // print 656667
    return 0;
}
```

edit: You asked for a conversion to int. I changed the code slightly to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the 'right thing' for you?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
        // considering you know the size of buffer here's the buffer
        const unsigned char buf[] = {'A', 'B', '\0', '\0', 'C', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        // 'conversion' happens here
        const std::vector<int> data(buf, buf + sizeof buf/sizeof 0[buf]);

        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

        return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
65 66 0 0 67 100 101 102
```

Of course no big deal putting that vector to a `stringstream` and then from it to and `int`, but it would overflow *very quickly*:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct PutElementToStream
{
        PutElementToStream(std::stringstream &stream)
                : stream_(stream)
        {}
        void operator()(int value)
        {
                stream_ << value;
        }

private:
        std::stringstream &stream_;
};

int main()
{
        const unsigned char buf[] = {'A', 'B', '\0', '\0', 'C', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        const std::vector<int> data(buf, buf + sizeof buf/sizeof 0[buf]);

        std::stringstream stream;
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), PutElementToStream(stream));

        std::cout << "stream: " << stream.str() << "\n";

        int value = 0;
        stream >> value;  // the sample array would overflow an int
        std::cout << "int value: " << value << "\n";

        const std::string string_value(stream.str());
        std::cout << "string value: " << string_value << "\n";

        return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
stream: 65660067100101102
int value: 0
string value: 65660067100101102
```